# Kafka command line tool to upload file as a single message?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a command line tool to upload a file as a single message in Kafka?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No such tool out of box, but you could implement it by invoking kafka-console-producer script to receive a single-line file, as shown below:

> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list broker1:9092 --topic test < your_file

Comment: Make sure the file is no larger than 1MB or it will fail to publish with the default configuration.

Comment: What is the key of the message will be?